# iTunes too slow: how to diagnose, how to avoid?

Tags: itunes, network

I am running iTunes on different Macs connected on Ethernet to download the last iOS version (10.1.?).

Note: Wi-Fi, Bluetooth are explictly off to be sure what I am analyzing.

On these different Macs, the download is similarly extremly slow:
[image: iTunes slow download]

The actual version of iTunes I run is:
    12.5.1.21

The actual connection I am using is:

```
Mac → Ethernet:    1 Gbit/s
router → Internet: 1 Gbit/s (shared by a few hundreds users).
```

With the help of a `tcpdump -i en0` I was able to diagnose I am actually
downloading an Internet monstruous mammoth from:

```
defra1-vip-bx-006.aaplimg.com
```

on port 80 (= http).

A rapid ping analysis gave me:

```
••My_Mac••$ ping -c 20 -s 1992 -q defra1-vip-bx-006.aaplimg.com
PING defra1-vip-bx-006.aaplimg.com (17.253.55.206): 1992 data bytes

--- defra1-vip-bx-006.aaplimg.com ping statistics ---
20 packets transmitted, 15 packets received, 25.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 27.732/28.388/28.798/0.285 ms
••My_Mac••$
```

when at the exact same time, a reference one (on the other side of the
world) gave me:

```
••My_Mac••$ ping -c 20 -s 1992 -q www.cisco.com
PING e144.dscb.akamaiedge.net (2.18.128.170): 1992 data bytes

--- e144.dscb.akamaiedge.net ping statistics ---
20 packets transmitted, 20 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.868/2.990/3.121/0.063 ms
••My_Mac••$
```

This looks like a network problem on Apple side.
My question is more general than the typical context of this case.

How may I test directly the Apple download server to check where the bottleneck is located and when I will be able to download this version
in a normal time?

How may I avoid an iTunes download when the connection to the Apple download servers is so bad (9 hours in this case)?

Comment: Seems you are having package loss,send out probes with different ttl value to locate the primary package loss source.

Comment: I think you meant packet loss :). Yes I know and analyse it. I am disappointed that a software upgrade process doesn't detect alone it is using a suicidal network connection.

Comment: Does downloading iOS firmware from a third party source working?